# Как ускорить работу скрипта в гугл таблицах?

Tags: производительность, google-apps-script, таблицы, макросы

Есть таблица в которой много листов. Часть ячеек заполнена значениями, часть - формулами. Требуется заблокировать ячейки с формулам от изменений. Нужно чтобы они были доступны для изменений только ограниченному кругу пользователей. Мне удалось написать этот скрипт, но он работает не быстро. Есть ли какие-то способы его ускорить?

```
function myFunction2() {
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
 
for(const sheeto of sheets) { //проводим перебор всех листов
 
 var ss1 = sheeto.getName();
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ss1);
 var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); 
 for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) { //удаляем имеющиеся блокировки при наличии
   var protection = protections[i];
   if (protection.canEdit()) {
     protection.remove();
   }
 }
 var arr2 = ss.getDataRange().getFormulas();
 var numRows = arr2.length-1;
 var numCols = arr2[0].length-1;
 for (var i = 0; i <= numCols; ++i) {
   for (var y = 0; y <= numRows; ++y) {
     if (arr2[y][i]!="") { //блокируем все с формулами
       var range = ss.getRange(y+1,i+1);
       var protection = range.protect().setDescription('автозащита');
       var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
       protection.addEditor(me);
       
       protection.addEditor('пользователь1');
       protection.addEditor('пользователь2');
       protection.addEditor('пользователь3');
       protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
       if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
         protection.setDomainEdit(false);

       }
     }
   }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

в общем решила сменить подход. Блокирую не отдельно диапазоны, а весь лист. Ячейки без формул, которые должны быть доступны к изменениям, сохраняю в массив. И этот массив передаю в блокировку листа в качестве диапазонов-исключений. При таком подходе получается гораздо быстрее.

```
function myFunction2() {
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  
for(const sheeto of sheets) {
  
  var ss1 = sheeto.getName();
  if  (ss1!="Лист1"  ) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ss1);
  

  var arr2 = ss.getDataRange().getFormulas();
  

  var numRows = arr2.length-1;
  var numCols = arr2[0].length-1;

var Range1 = new Array(0);
var Range2 = new Array(0);
var Range3 = new Array(1);
vyh: {
  for (var i = 3; i <= numRows; ++i) {
    for (var y = 3; y <= numCols; ++y) {
      if (arr2[i][y]!="") {
        
        
       

      }
      else{
        yy=y+1
        ii=i+1
        Range1.length=Range1.length+1
        Range1[Range1.length-1]=yy 
        Range2.length=Range2.length+1
        Range2[Range2.length-1]=ii 

      }  
    }
  }

}

Range3[0]=col2A1(Range1[0]) + Range2[0]
ii=1
f=0
for (var i = 1; i <= Range1.length-1; ++i){

  if (Range2[i]==Range2[i-1] && Range1[i-1]==Range1[i]-1) {
    if (f==0) {
    Range3[ii-1] = Range3[ii-1] + ":" + col2A1(Range1[i]) + Range2[i]
    f=1
    }
    else{
      Range3[ii-1]=Range3[ii-1].slice(0, Range3[ii-1].indexOf(":")) + ":" + col2A1(Range1[i]) + Range2[i]
      
    }
  }
  else {
    Range3[ii]=col2A1(Range1[i]) + Range2[i]
    ii=ii+1
    f=0

  }

 }



var protection = ss.protect().setDescription('автозащита листа');

var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);

protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
var protection = ss.protect();

var unprotected = protection.getUnprotectedRanges();

 for (var i = 0; i <= Range3.length-1; ++i){
unprotected.push(ss.getRange(Range3[i]));
protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotected);


 }
 }
}
}  


function col2A1(col){
  let result = "";
  let base = 27;
  while(col>0){    
    let newLetter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)+(col-1)%(base-1));  
    result=newLetter + result;
    col = (col - col%base) / base;
  };
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Если это ответ - отметьте его как решение, пожалуйста.